# load array from a file

Tags: c, file-handling

I'm saving the elements of array using `fwrite` and I'm trying to load that previous saved data to the array using `fread`. The return value of `fread` is non-zero, which means it was successful. But when I print the array, it's empty, nothing is getting printed.
I've saved the array to a file as

```
fwrite(num, sizeof(int), k, q); //num is the same array, k=no of elements, q is the file pointer
```

Here's my code :

```
int num[50], NoOfElement;
FILE *p;
if(p = fopen("data.txt", "rb") == NULL)
{
    printf("Error");
    exit(1);
}
fseek(p, 0, SEEK_END);
NoOfElement = ftell(p) / sizeof(int); //no of elements in the file
fseek(p, 0, SEEK_SET);
fread(num, sizeof(int), NoOfElement, p);
```

Comment: `p`? `freed`???

Comment: Array cannot be empty.

Comment: sorry, It's `fread` and `p` is the file pointer

Comment: @mukeshbhadotri Nops,  the file pointer is `P`

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems fine. This demo program works OK for me:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int num[50], NoOfElement;
    FILE *P;
    int i;

    // Generate test data
    for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
        num[i] = i+1;

    // Write test data
    P = fopen("data.txt", "wb");
    fwrite(num, sizeof(int), 5, P);
    fclose(P);

    // Overwrite the test data so we know we read it OK
    for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
        num[i] = -1;

    // Your code for reading test data
    if((P = fopen("data.txt", "rb")) == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error");
        exit(1);
    }
    fseek(P, 0, SEEK_END);
    NoOfElement = ftell(P) / sizeof(int); //no of elements in the file
    fseek(P, 0, SEEK_SET);
    fread(num, sizeof(int), NoOfElement, P);

    // Output test data (shows 1 -> 5 as expected)
    for (i = 0; i < NoOfElement; ++i)
        printf("%d\n", num[i]);
}
```

Comment: I don't think it's working.. May be it's showing the values right from the array, not from the file

Comment: @mukeshbhadotri It is working. I specifically rewrite the values to be `-1` in my example to prove that it's not showing the original values. You have to read from the file back into memory -- you're not showing anything "from the file". You can copy and paste my code and run it yourself to check.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems I can see. The first is that you use an undeclared variable `p` (you had declared `FILE *P;` and C is case-sensitive).

But assuming that was a typo in transcription, and not in your actual code, you also have a buffer overflow issue. If `NoOfElement > 50`, you will invoke undefined behavior and (potentially) corrupt your stack.

How are you printing the array, anyway.

Comment: `NoOfElement` will never be greater than 50, because first I'm calculating no of bytes of the file and dividing it with `sizeof(int)`. so it'll always be less than 50. because elements(>50) of that array is stored in that file, it can't be higher a value

Comment: But the file could be bigger than `50*sizeof(int)` (200, assuming 32-bit ints) bytes

Comment: `50*sizeof(int) = 200bytes` but `NoOfElement = 200bytes / sizeof(int)` (result is 50)

Comment: I entered 5 elements, saved it to the file. The file size was 20 bytes. Tried with 3 elements, size was 12 bytes.

Comment: Yes, but what if you have a 800 byte file? then `NoOfElement = 500/sizeof(int) = 200`

Comment: `for(i = 0; i < NoOfElement; i++) printf("%d ", num[i]);` this is how I'm printing

Comment: !st I'm saving the data of the array to the file. That is always less than 50. That's why I have to calculate the no of elements every time. I'm not appending data to the same file.